# Hand code a stellar transaction

Tags: stellar-core, transactions

I know how bitcoin transactions are built 4 Bytes version & 1 byte number of inputs ...etc 
similar to this how is stellar transaction built and signed ? 
Please help me find that information ? where should I start looking ?

please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know in deep detail but... afaik a stellar transaction is a bunch of [XDR (External Data Representation Standard)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4506.html#section-3) encoded data. I'm not aware of an official definition document but you can find definition files in the stellar base libraries (for example [js-stellar-base](https://github.com/stellar/js-stellar-base/tree/master/xdr) or [ruby-stellar-base](https://github.com/stellar/ruby-stellar-base/tree/master/xdr)). The transaction is [Ed25519](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to/) signed and tx+signature are combined in a XDR TransactionEnvelope structure. Finally the resulting XDR chunk is usually base64 encoded for transfer.

I think it's pretty complicated to do this by hand on the lowest binary level. If you're looking for a higher level entry, the stellar laboratory is an excellent tool to [build a transaction XDR string](https://laboratory.stellar.org/#txbuilder), [sign a XDR string](https://laboratory.stellar.org/#txsigner?network=test) or [decode a XDR string](https://laboratory.stellar.org/#xdr-viewer).

Comment: This was the closest I got to understand transaction structure behind stellar 
https://github.com/KingHodor/Stellar-XDR

Also if I decode raw xdr tx to hex everything is serialized in big endian